# How to aggregate different field by a date field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

REST api call

```
GET test10/LREmail10/_search/
    {
       "size": 10,
       "query": {
          "range": {
             "ALARM DATE": {
                "gte": "now-15d/d",
                "lt": "now/d"
             }
          }
       },
       "fields": [
          "ALARM DATE",
          "CLASSIFICATION"
       ]
    }
```

part of out put is,

```
 "took": 25,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 490,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test10",
            "_type": "LREmail10",
            "_id": "AVM5g6XaShke4hy5dziK",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "CLASSIFICATION": [
                  "Attack"
               ],
               "ALARM DATE": [
                  "25/02/2016 8:35:22 AM(UTC-08:00)"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test10",
            "_type": "LREmail10",
            "_id": "AVM5g6e_Shke4hy5dziL",
            "_score": 1,
            "fields": {
               "CLASSIFICATION": [
                  "Compromise"
               ],
               "ALARM DATE": [
                  "25/02/2016 8:36:16 AM(UTC-08:00)"
               ]
            }
         },
```

What I really want to do here is, aggregate CLASSIFICATION by ALARM DATE. Default format of the date has minutes, seconds and time-zone too. But I want to aggrigate all the classifications for each and everydate. So, `"25/02/2016 8:36:16 AM(UTC-08:00)"` and  `"25/02/2016 8:35:22 AM(UTC-08:00)"` should be considered as  `"25/02/2016"` date. and get the all the classifications belong to a single date.

I wish that I have explained question properly. If you guys need any more details let me know.

If anyone, can give me a hint to look what area in Elasticsearch is also very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date_histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) like below.

```
 {
 "size" :0 ,
 "aggs": {
        "classification of day": {
           "date_histogram": {
              "field": "ALARM DATE",
              "interval": "day"
           },
           "aggs": {
              "classification": {
                 "terms": {
                    "field": "CLASSIFICATION"
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```